# SVG marker-end only appears when not dynamically created (innerHTML = innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, svg, dom

This was a pretty remarkable bug, and I'm still not sure how to solve it. The charitable interpretation is that I got the semantics of `document.createElementNS` wrong, and the not-so-charitable is that every major browser has a bug. I'll hope it's the former.

When dynamically creating an SVG path with a `marker-end`, using a `url(#id)` reference to a `<marker>`, the `marker-end` does not render. However, the *identical* HTML source, when inserted all-at-once, renders properly. See the following example. When you press the "make it good" button, the only code that runs is:
`svg.innerHTML = svg.innerHTML`! As you should see, the arrowhead only appears when the button is clicked.

```js
const elem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");

const id = `arrowhead_2`;

const marker = document.createElementNS(
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
    "marker"
  );
marker.setAttribute("id", id);
marker.setAttribute("markerUnits", "strokeWidth");
marker.setAttribute("markerWidth", "6.97");
marker.setAttribute("markerHeight", "5.68");
marker.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 9.95 8.12");
marker.setAttribute("refX", "2.36");
marker.setAttribute("refY", "4.06");
marker.setAttribute("orient", "auto-start-reverse");
const path = document.createElementNS("svg", "path");
path.setAttribute("d", "M9.95 4.06 0 8.12 2.36 4.06 0 0 9.95 4.06z");
path.setAttribute("fill", "#00cc00");
path.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "1");
marker.appendChild(path);

const arrow = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
arrow.appendChild(marker);

const arrowPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
arrowPath.setAttribute("d", "M0 10 L10.0981265193531 28.49209939676484");
arrowPath.setAttribute("marker-end", `url(#${id})`);
arrowPath.setAttribute("fill", "#00cc00");
arrowPath.setAttribute("fill-opacity", "1");
arrowPath.setAttribute("stroke", "#00cc00");
arrowPath.setAttribute("stroke-width", "3");

arrow.appendChild(arrowPath);

const svg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
svg.appendChild(arrow);

document.getElementById("makegood").onclick = () => {
    svg.innerHTML = svg.innerHTML; 
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="makegood">make it good</button>
<svg
    id="mysvg"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        version="1.2"
        viewBox="0 0 100 100"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      ></svg>
</html>
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: document.createElementNS("svg", "path"); "svg" is not a valid namespace. You get it right earlier and also later in the document.

Comment: OMG, thank you @RobertLongson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert in the comments nailed it, it's the line

`const path = document.createElementNS("svg", "path");`

which should actually be

`const path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");`